# Paged LDap search fails with "The requested attribute does not exists"

Tags: c#, ldap

I need to get the 'employeenumber' of all the employees whose 'epersonstatus=REMOVE' using an Ldap search implemented using .NET/C# like:

```
var connection = new LdapConnection("foo.bar.com:389");

connection.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
connection.Bind();

var request = new SearchRequest(
                 "dc=root,dc=com",
                 "(epersonstatus=REMOVE)", 
                 SearchScope.Subtree,
                 new string[] { "employeenumber" });
```

Since there are thousands of entries I am using paged requests as proposed here:
http://dunnry.com/blog/PagingInSystemDirectoryServicesProtocols.aspx

I have also checked that the server supports paged requests as proposed here:
[iPlanet LDAP and C# PageResultRequestControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646518/iplanet-ldap-and-c-sharp-pageresultrequestcontrol)

Once the flow reaches:

```
SearchResponse response = connection.SendRequest(request) as SearchResponse;
```

I get a DirectoryOperationException with message "The requested attribute does not exist".

By running the same query on a LDap client like softerra I get the entries (a thousand) and
the error.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.

When using paged search, I got the exception `"The server does not support the control. The control is critical."`, when using non-paged search I received results (at least as long as the filter restricted the maximum number).

However I found out, that the error message is misleading - The problem was buried in the authentication.

Using `AuthType.Basic` (or `AuthType.Anonymous`) I received the error. Bus as soon as I switched to `AuthType.Ntlm` it worked.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This helped, thanks.  I was having a similar issue, where on a domain joined server, Basic was working fine, but once released to a non domain joined server it was failing at the same point.  Ensuring that I was using AuthType.Ntlm allowed the request to succeed.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, this helped me too. I had posted a question here [How to resolve “The server does not support the control. The control is critical.” Active Directory error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634669/how-to-resolve-the-server-does-not-support-the-control-the-control-is-critical) and then found this.