# How to get all supported ldap controls in .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I want to know is there any api provided in .Net to get all supported ldap controls for given domain ? In 'Ldp' utility when we bind to certain domain we get to see all supported ldap controls OID. I want this list through .Net.  Or is it possible that check if certain ldap control is supported when OID of control is provided.

Comment: I got answer from one of the stackoverflow thread. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646518/iplanet-ldap-and-c-sharp-pageresultrequestcontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from one of the stackoverflow thread. 
[iPlanet LDAP and C# PageResultRequestControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646518/iplanet-ldap-and-c-sharp-pageresultrequestcontrol)

```
LdapConnection lc = new LdapConnection("ldap.server.name");
// Reading the Root DSE can always be done anonymously, but the AuthType
// must be set to Anonymous when connecting to some directories:
lc.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;
using (lc)
{
  // Issue a base level search request with a null search base:
  SearchRequest sReq = new SearchRequest(
    null,
    "(objectClass=*)",
    SearchScope.Base,
    "supportedControl");
  SearchResponse sRes = (SearchResponse)lc.SendRequest(sReq);
  foreach (String supportedControlOID in
    sRes.Entries[0].Attributes["supportedControl"].GetValues(typeof(String)))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(supportedControlOID);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation that tells you which LDAP controls are supported:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813628(v=vs.85).aspx